# Implementing plugins cakePHP

Tags: sql, shell, cakephp, plugins

I am trying to implement a search plugin that I found into an application I am creating.

[This is the plugin](http://www.neilcrookes.com/2009/11/21/cakephp-searchable-plugin/);

So far I have put the plugin into `'..cakePHP/app/Plugin/'`, added `CakePlugin::loadAll()` in the bootstrap config file and ran the SQL query it mentions, which all worked fine.

The problem is when I try the next step and run `'cake build_search_index'` in terminal from the path `'app pjmil$'`, I get;

```
'Error: Shell class BuildSearchIndexShell could not be found.'
```

Am I trying to execute the command in shell from the wrong path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that plugin is for Cakephp 1.x, not 2.x.

Comment: @pjmil116: If tigrang's answer was helpful, consider marking it as accepted to reward him with some imaginary internet points.